# How do I override a SteamVR Controller's transforms in Unity?

Tags: unity, virtual-reality, htc-vive, steam-vr

I'm trying to provide an illusion to the user by rotating the controller about an arbitrary axis in the LateUpdate() method. But this doesn't seem to be having any effect as the controller probably is constantly getting updated by its real world location. Is there any way to override its real world position and orientation with a transformation in script?

Comment: Have you considered hiding the "real" controller object and adding your own "fake" visible object that follows the hidden object, with your extra rotation layered-on?

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks for your suggestion. That's exactly what I tried to do next, but the fake object(attached to the SteamVR controller) also doesn't seem to obey the transforms I impose.

Comment: Did you try not attaching it?

Comment: Interesting, but then I'm not sure how I could make it follow the controller movements. Can you please suggest a way to do that @DMGregory ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend hiding the "real" controller object, and creating your own visible object that matches its movements plus an offset you control, something like this:

```
public class FollowWithATwist : MonoBehaviour {

    // Set this to point at your controller
    public Transform objectToFollow;

    // Set this to the twist you want to apply
    public Quaternion extraRotation;


    void LateUpdate() {
         transform.position = objectToFollow.position;

         // This applies the twist in the controller's local space.
         // Flip the multiplication order if you want it applied in world space.
         transform.rotation = objectToFollow.rotation * extraRotation;
    }
}
```

If you want the object to interact with physics, then do this in FixedUpdate by applying forces/torques to the rigidbody instead, to minimize teleportation artifacts. I have previous answers showing [how to do this with velocity for translation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/180162/39518) and [torque for rotation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/182061/39518).