# Unity: Stop Rigidbody from moving in one direction

Tags: unity, 3d, rigidbody

I move a rigidbody by moving the mouse.

I want my rigidbody to stop moving in the x direction when it exceeds a certain range. To do that I set the x velocity to 0. If I log the velocity, the x-value is 0 when I exceed the range, but somehow it is still moving slightly.
The following answer **SOLVED** it for me: [Limit position rigidbody](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/180132/limit-position-rigidbody)

You need to put the code that controlls the range inside Update or LateUpdate and in General, it is better to use Math.Clamp instead of the if-statements

```
    //React on user input
    float xForce = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
    float yForce = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

    xForce *= Time.fixedDeltaTime * speed;
    yForce *= Time.fixedDeltaTime * speed;

    handRb.AddForce(new Vector3( xForce,  yForce, 0));

    //Check, if hand is movable in current Direction
    Vector2 currentPos = hand.localPosition;
    float xVelocity = handRb.velocity.x;
    float yVelocity = handRb.velocity.y;

    if ((currentPos.x <= (-movementPlaneScale.x / 2) && (xVelocity < 0)) || (currentPos.x >= (movementPlaneScale.x / 2) && (xVelocity > 0)))
    {
        xVelocity = 0;
    }

    if ((currentPos.y <= (movementPlaneOriginY - (movementPlaneScale.y / 2)) && (yVelocity < 0)) || (currentPos.y >= (movementPlaneOriginY + (movementPlaneScale.y / 2)) && (yVelocity > 0)))
    {
        yVelocity = 0;
    }

    Debug.Log(xVelocity);
    handRb.velocity = new Vector3(xVelocity, yVelocity, 0);
```

How can I stop the rigidbody from moving along one axis?

Comment: This looks similar to a [recent question about limiting the position of a Rigidbody](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/180132/39518) — are you able to apply the techniques from answers there to solve your problem?

Comment: @DMGregory Yes, that solved it for me. Thanks!