# How to rotate a rigidbody with a Pid controller

Tags: unity, c#, physics, rotation

I would like someone to describe me how to use a PID controller to rotate a rigidbody with AddTorque to a specific position. (like a spacecraft that rotates the Y axis of rotation towards Camera.forward for example). Can anyone show it to me with a script?

Actually I already use this script to rotate with AddTorque but the object almost never stops at the precise point.

```
Vector3 camForward = Camera.main.transform.forward;
Vector3 rbForward = rb.transform.forward;
Vector3 torqueY = Vector3.Project(torque, Vector3.up);
Vector3 torque = Vector3.Cross(camForward, rbForward);
rb.AddTorque(torque);
rb.AddTorque(-rb.angularVelocity);
```

Comment: [I show how to apply a torque to reach a specific orientation in this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/182873/39518) - it's not specifically a PID approach, but you may be able to adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I already use this script to rotate (I posted the code in the answer), but the object never stops at the precise point, for this reason I was recommended a PID. Searching I also found a PID that looks good (it is used in a video to rotate an object), if i publish it could you show me how to set it to make it work for the purpose?